# Internal Server Error (500) when doing SOAP request

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, httpwebrequest

I am trying to do a SOAP request but the server is returning an 500 error. 
The SOAP request returns correctly the XML message via jmeter for example, so it must be something in my code, but i fail to see what. Can you help?

```
private void soapRequest(string regID)
        {

            string soapReq= @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>";
            soapReq= "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:mpc=\"urn://mobility-platform.de/mpcustomerdb/\">\n";
            soapReq += "<soapenv:Header/>\n";
            soapReq += "<soapenv:Body>\n";
            soapReq += "<mpc:findRegistrationByID>\n";
            soapReq += "<registrationID>" + regID + "</registrationID>\n";
            soapReq += "</mpc:findRegistrationByID>\n";
            soapReq += "</soapenv:Body>\n";
            soapReq += "</soapenv:Envelope>";

            //Builds the connection to the WebService.
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://url?wsdl");
            req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");            
            req.Headers.Add("SOAP:Action");
            req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            req.Accept = "text/xml";
            req.Method = "POST";

            //Passes the SoapRequest String to the WebService
            using (Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
            {
                using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
                {
                    stmw.Write(soapReq.ToString());                    
                }
            }
            try
            {
                //Gets the response
                HttpWebResponse soapResponse = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                //Writes the Response
                Stream responseStream = soapResponse.GetResponseStream();
                //read the stream
                XmlDocument soapResponseXML = new XmlDocument();

                StreamReader responseStreamRead = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                soapResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
                //MessageBox.Show(responseStreamRead.ReadToEnd().ToString());
                string soapURL = responseStreamRead.ReadToEnd().ToString();

                soapResponseXML.LoadXml(soapURL);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Here is the soap request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mpc="urn://mobility-platform.de/mpcustomerdb/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mpc:findRegistrationByID>
         <registrationID>2304580</registrationID>
      </mpc:findRegistrationByID>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Later edit:**
If i change 

`req.Headers.Add("SOAP:Action");` to:


`req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", ""\"http://url\"" + "findRegistrationByID");` 

i get an different error:
 **"This property is not implemented by this class"**

Comment: **a)** Never build XML from strings. **b)** Your `req.Accept = "text/xml";` could be wrong. What `Content-Type` does the server return with a successful response? That's the one you should set `Accept` to.

Comment: Do you have access to the server in question? If so, the application log in Event Viewer should have some helpful information.

Comment: I think i am doing something wrong here: `req.Headers.Add("SOAP:Action");` and it should be something like: `req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", ""\"http://url\"" + "findRegistrationByID");`  but if i change it like that i get the following error  **this property is not implemented by this class**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not very easy to make an proper soap request with this method. I am strongly recommending to use rather the whole web service, and rather make the request like this:

```
WebService aa = new WebService;
registrationName = aa.findRegistrationByID("123");
```

This will accomplish all the above code ;)